# Is there an IE 7 workaround for floating elements not clearing properly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I see plenty of IE 7 workarounds for other CSS float problems, but I have yet to find one for this issue: when an element has both `clear` and `float` properties, the clearing doesn't work correctly.

[This jsFiddle illustrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9qwJX/).  I'm trying to solve a very basic problem.  I have a form with label/form item pairs.  The labels should be on the left, and the form item should be to the right of the label.  The next label should display on the next line.  With this simple HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <label>Label 1:</label>
  <input type="text" />

  <label>Label 2:</label>
  <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

This CSS should be sufficient:

```
label {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

input {
    float: left;
}
```

However, what's happening instead is that although the second label clears the float and is rendered on the next line, the adjacent input is still shown on the first line.

Is there any workaround for this problem beyond adding more markup?

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose the groups in a seperate div, the problem is solved.  Of course you don't even need the clear then at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh87k/1/